# Inspecting IOS devices on chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, safari, profiling

I have following questions...

1. I am simply using javascript profiling provided by google chrome, to optimize performance of my application. I actually needs to optimize performance on IOS device but not aware about how to do it from chrome. How can I do it?
2. I have tried to do it from safari itself but I am unable to find Javascript  profiling option in safari. What kind of option there in safari for this?
3. Also can you please let me know how to save profile in safari as we do in chrome.

> I don't want to confuse with timeline performance option. I am asking
>   about javascript profiling option in safari like chrome. I am using safari version 9.0.2

Thank you,
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you connect your iOS device to the computer and enable the remote debugging through safari ([A simple guide](http://moduscreate.com/enable-remote-web-inspector-in-ios-6/)), click on "Timeline" tab. You may find the "recording" option there, together with the panels for performance debugging of "Network Requests", "Layout & Rendering" and "Javascript & Events". Is that what you want?

Check this out to save the profile: https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy

Comment: I have gone through this option. but can we do javascript profiling like in chrome we do? and can we save this profile?

Comment: Yeah, right now I am viewing same link actually... Will it solve  my problem??

Comment: And.. can you please tell me how to see that saved javascript profile back in to the browser? Or I have to ask new question for this?

Comment: ok I got how to load saved profile... Thanks for your help @Hammer!!